# Selecting values in columns using grep

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = 
name1 name2 Value
Dii   Rif   8
Dif   Dib   5
Fih   Qiv   6
```

I would like to select the row with the following combination:

```
combination = 'if|ii'
```

In other words, to select those values of the columns `name1` and `name2` that have any of the members of the vector `combination`. Remember that they must both values be in there. In this case ONLY the first row should be selected.

this is what I have tried:

```
df <- df %>%
   select(grep(combination, c('name1', 'name2')))
```

But I get an empty `df`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, I think you want to use `filter` instead of `select`, one way to go would be:

```r
library(dplyr)

combination <- "if|ii"

df %>%
  filter(grepl(combination, name1), grepl(combination, name2))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   name1 name2 Value
#>   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 Dii   Rif       8
```